# How to solve an `unchecked` Java warning about a Class requiring to extend from a specific class?

Tags: java, class, generics

In my Android Java application I have a method:

```
private <T extends Message> ReturnObject doSomething(Class<T> type) {
    // Implementation
}
```

As you see parameter `type` should extend of class `Message`.

Now, this is the case; I call the method `doSomething` like:

```
@Override
public void myMethod(Class type){
    doSomething(type);
}
```

Notice that my method overrides another method.

The warning that pops up:

```
[unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method doSomething in class 
Class is applied to given types
required: Class<T>
found: Class
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Message declared in method <T>doSomething(String,Class<T>)
```

How can I solve this warning?

Comment: Can you share the code of complete function ?

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo. Khalid, I think the rest of the code is not relevant for this question

Comment: "found: Class". So, you're giving it a raw type. Please show how you are calling this method.

Comment: Your method call should be something along the lines of `doSomething(Message.class)`

Comment: You are using a raw type. **Never do that.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void myMethod(Class type) {
    Class<? extends Message> mtype = type.asSubclass(Message.class);
    doSomething(mtype);
}
```

Best would be to remove the non-generic type-unsafe overriden method:

```
public void myMethod(Class<?> type) {
```

And even *more best* to repair the base class method.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like

```
public <T extends Message> void myMethod(Class<T> type){
    doSomething(type);
}
```

Comment: If I change it like this I get the error: `Invalid method declaration; return type required`

Comment: @Klyner I didn't check the syntax, probably the <...> goes before the declaration of the return type (void).

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot to mention that `myMethod` is overriding another method having a parameter `type` with type `Class` so I think that I need to convert it or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pass the Class type in the parameter and not just the Class like this below

```
@Override
public void myMethod(Class<T> type){//I've changed the parameter from Class to Class<T>
    doSomething(type);
}
```